# Optimisation with polynomial constraints (Z3)?

Tags: optimization, z3, z3py

I'm wondering if it's possible to solve optimisation problems that have polynomial constraints? In particular I'm wondering with regards to Z3.

In a Z3 tutorial it says it supports polynomial constraints, but I don't know if that applies to optimisation, or if that is just for constraint solving.

Many thanks, all answers greatly appreciated.

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Constraints of the form `x^n + x^(n-1) + ... + c = k` introduce non-linear terms. (Two variables being multiplied; in this case the same one.) And z3's optimizer does not deal with non-linear constraints. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50319193/936310 for details.