# Optimize() in z3py not finding optimal solutions

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, z3, z3py

I'm trying to use z3py as an optimization solver to maximise the volume of a cuboid cut out from a piece of paper. The python API provides the Optimize() object but using it seems to be unreliable, giving me solutions that are obviously inaccurate.

I've tried using `h = opt.maximise` followed by `opt.upper(h)` as well as simply checking the model, as well as defining the volume of the cuboid before adding it to the model `v = w*b*l` and after, as well as setting the objective as `w*b*l` instead of `v`. None of them have given me anything resembling a good solution.

```py
from z3 import *
l = Real("l")
w = Real("w")
b = Real("b")
v = Real("v")
opt = Optimize()
width = 63.6
height = 51

opt.add(b+l <= width)
opt.add(w+b+w+l+w <= height)
opt.add(w > 0)
opt.add(b > 0)
opt.add(l > 0)
opt.add(v == w*b*l)
opt.maximize(w * b * l)
# h = opt.maximize(v)


print(opt.check())
# print(opt.upper(h))
print(opt.model())
```

Outputs:

```
unknown
[w = 1, b = 1, l = 47, v = 47]
```

This definitely is not the maximum. Setting all values to 10 gives a greater solution that fulfills the constraints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Z3's optimizer does not handle non-linear problems. And indeed, that's precisely why it prints `unknown`. When you see a call to `check` returning `unknown` it precisely means that: Z3 does not know whether the problem is satisfiable or not, let alone if it has found the optimum solution.

If you add:

```
print(opt.reason_unknown())
```

after the call to `check`, you'll see:

```
(incomplete (theory arithmetic))
```

In these cases, the call to `model` will return some intermediate result `z3` obtained as it worked on the problem, but by no means it is guaranteed to be optimal.

Your problem is non-linear because you are multiplying variables. (`w`, `b`, and `l`.) Z3 *can* solve nonlinear satisfiability problems over reals, but *not* optimization problems. See, for instance, here: [z3Opt optimize non-linear function using qfnra-nlsat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975703/z3opt-optimize-non-linear-function-using-qfnra-nlsat)

(Note that nonlinear optimization is a significantly harder problem for reals as opposed to pure satisfiability. So, it's not just a matter of "not having implemented it yet.")

Comment: "Your problem is non-linear because you are multiplying variables. (w, b, and l.) Z3 can solve nonlinear satisfiability problems over reals, but not optimization problems. See, for instance, here: " This is what confused me. Thanks for clearing that up. I assumed Z3 also could do nonlinear (polynomial) optimization when it it can do satisfiability problems.